# Matter wave of macroscopic objects

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, wave-particle-duality

By De-Broglie's hypothesis it can be said that every matter has a dual nature associated with it, and the relationship being:

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{p}$$
Now by applying this relation on a macroscopic object like a ball of mass 1 kg going at a velocity of 1 m/s, we get its matter wave to be of order -34, which is *pretty insignificant* so we ignore it.

But a wave of such *small wavelength* will possess a lot of energy
(as its frequency will be pretty high) and we should observe some strange/harmful effects by throwing the ball, but I see none.

What is the possible explanation for this?

Comment: Did you calculate the energy of the ball?

Comment: The energy of the ball is at least 89,875,517,873,681,764 Joules.

Comment: isn't this the reason ?       $E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$ and $\lambda=\frac{h}{p}$ are two seprate equations( one for EM waves and other for matter waves). One cannot mix them with each other. So the real energy of the ball is just its KE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that you are thinking that the energy of a photon is given by:

$$ E = h\nu \tag{1} $$

so this should apply to a matter wave as well. Then since the frequency of a matter wave should be extremely high it will have an extremely high energy. We can work through the calculation of this energy and see what happens.

We start by using the well known equation:

$$ v_p = \nu \lambda \tag{2} $$

where here $v_p$ is the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) of a wave. For a photon $v_p = c$ but for a matter wave $v_p = \tfrac12 v_g$, where $v_g$ is the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity). The group velocity is what we think of as the velocity of an object like a ball, so lets just call the group velocity $v$.

Anyhow, substitute $\nu = v_p/\lambda$ into equation (1) and we get:

$$ E = \frac{hv_p}{\lambda} $$

then $v_p = \tfrac12v$ to get:

$$ E = \tfrac12 \frac{hv}{\lambda} $$

then $p = h/\lambda$ to get:

$$ E = \tfrac12 pv $$

and by now I'm sure you can see where this is going. Substitute $p = mv$ and we get:

$$ E = \tfrac12 mv^2 $$

which is of course the usual expression for the kinetic energy of a macroscopic object. So the equations we use for a quantum particle do indeed apply to the ball, at least in principle, but they just end up giving the usual classical result.